# JavaScript Intellisense is not working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I know there are ALLOT of duplicates to this problem on SO as well as all over the web. Unfortunately, nothing that was suggested is working. I've done everything with the exception of reinstalling VS'15 (Id rather not if I can help it).

One site I went to: [The story behind _references.js](http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs) and an interesting thing appeared (or rather it didn't) in the JavaScript Intellisense section of the Text Editor in options. The reference to the _references.js file was not  there. However after adding this reference, there is still not intellisense.

Is there anything I can do to get my intellisense back?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After many hours of banging my head against my desk, I found the answer to this weird issue. Turns out that the bootstrap.min.js script was interfering with the JavaScript intellisense. So I just commented out the script in my _references.js file. Also, I changed the autosync to false and instantly the intellisense came back.

Comment: this put me on the right path, but instead of bootstrap.min it was jquery-ui-1.11.4.js - and I didn't need to turn off autosync. I have 111 references in my file, had to go through and comment them out in blocks just to narrow it down.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order of plugin references in your **_references.js** file.

In my case it was the *JQuery-UI* which I needed to move **above** the main *JQuery* reference, as explained in this post: [jQuery UI breaks Visual Studio 2015 Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49268281/3164801)